# I want to use multiple table query for login

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code that i am trying to query from multiple table but same column data, but not execute this code for success. please help me.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT id, name, department, session, username, email, rudf_position 
    FROM member, executive 
    WHERE username = ? AND mobile = ? ");
```

Comment: You need a joining condition that relates the two tables.

Comment: What error are you getting? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Comment: if try to login with member table info its OK,  but by executive table is not OK.

Comment: if try to login with membe or executive table , there is no incorrect password  or email. just showing nothing

Comment: You mean the user might be in one table or the other, not both?

Comment: users are in two table named "member" and "executive"

Comment: Did you add error reporting like I said you should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UNION` to search both tables independently.

```
SELECT id, name, department, session, username, email, rudf_position 
FROM member
WHERE username = ? AND mobile = ?
UNION
SELECT id, name, department, session, username, email, rudf_position 
FROM executive
WHERE username = ? AND mobile = ?
```

Comment: not working. show nothing, not showing any incorrect  message.

Comment: If you're not getting an error message and it's not returning any results, then there must not be any matches for the username and mobile.

Comment: but from individually table get result successfully

Comment: Did you remember to duplicate the arguments to `bind_param`, since there are now 4 placeholders?

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username, $mobile);  ...its  one line

Comment: But now there are 4 placeholders, it needs to be `$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $mobile, $username, $mobile);`